# How to Mysql ASC order 1,2,3,4,5 not 1,10,11,12?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Here is my query

```
$sql=executeQuery("select * from ".PREFIX."frame_info 
                   where Id='".$Id."' $where_clause 
                   order by left(FName, 2), substr(FName, 3) + 0, FName");
```

PS. I have tried the following but nothing worked

1. cast(FName as unsigned) ASC
2. FName + 0
3. LENGTH(FName), FName

Here is the sample data:

```
Rayban Slim Fit 5,
Rayban Slim Fit 6,
Rayban Slim Fit 7,
Rayban Slim Fit 3,
Rayban Slim Fit 2,
Rayban Slim Fit 1,
Rayban Slim Fit 9,
Rayban Slim Fit 8,
Rayban Slim Fit 10,
Rayban Princess 149,
Rayban Princess 146,
Rayban Princess 118,
Rayban Princess 147,
Rayban 3141,
Rayban 3143,
Rayban 3153,
Rayban 3152,
Rayban 3130,
Rayban 3128
```

Expected result:

```
Rayban 3128,
Rayban 3130,
Rayban 3141,
Rayban 3143,
Rayban 3152,
Rayban 3153,
Rayban Princess 118,
Rayban Princess 146,
Rayban Princess 147,
Rayban Princess 149,
Rayban Slim Fit 1,
Rayban Slim Fit 2,
Rayban Slim Fit 3,
Rayban Slim Fit 5,
Rayban Slim Fit 6,
Rayban Slim Fit 7,
Rayban Slim Fit 8,
Rayban Slim Fit 9,
Rayban Slim Fit 10
```

Comment: Show us your sample data. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: i have added the sample data

Comment: What would be expected output as per your sample data ?

Comment: added expected result

Comment: @ncksteven, what is your mysql version

Comment: mysql version: 5.5.51-38.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- We can use [Substring_Index()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function with Delimiter as a single space character (`' '`). `-1` will allow us to get the susbtring from end of the `FName` to the first occurence of space (right to left).
- Now, we can use `CAST(.. AS UNSIGNED)` to convert the number substring to integer.
- Use [`Replace()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) function with [`Trim()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim), to get the base name (string without the number suffix).
- Now, just `Order By` base name first and then the suffix number ("serial number")

Try the following query (**[DB Fiddle DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9AUF1iuvWdLFyYaXAwaB93/0)**):

```
SELECT Cast(Substring_index(fi.fname, ' ', -1) AS UNSIGNED) AS serial_number,
       Trim(REPLACE(fi.fname, Substring_index(fi.fname, ' ', -1), '')) AS
       FName_without_serialno, 
       fi.*
FROM   frame_info AS fi
ORDER  BY fname_without_serialno,
          serial_number
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks. It is working fine but the images and links are not loading.

Comment: @ncksteven what I have given is a general query. You will have to change your PHP code to suit to this query, with PHP variables used etc

Comment: How can i get the other fields from the same table because i have used select *

Comment: GREAT. Working awesome.